# Visual Studio 2017 nmake missing io.h

Tags: visual-c++, taglib, nmake

I am using the Enterprise Edition of Visual Studio 2017 and try to compile the neon library.
I call nmake from the visual command prompt. But I always get the error message, that the neccesary io.h file can not be find.
I have installed the Windows Kits and for example under Progarm Files\Windows Kits\10\10.0.1.17763\ucrt\io.h there is a io.h file. But nmake does not find it.
I also set a path to this directory, but it does not work.

Can somebody tell me, how to tell nmake to use this folder?
I found something about a tools.ini file but no instruction how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

After long time I found a solution.
First you have to press the windows icon (left low corner) and open your Visual Studio Version, open Developer input window.
In the input window change to the \Program (x86)\"Edition"\VC\Auxiliary\Build and execute the vcvars32.bat.
Then the compiler will find the necessary libraries.
(Please note, that I don't have an english version, so the folder could be named a little bit different)

I had also a second problem, where in the config.h file the definition of snprintf made son problem. I had to replace

```
#define snprintf _snprintf
```

with

```
#if (_MSC_VER < 1900) 
#define snprintf _snprintf
#endif
```

to solve this problem.